# Sprites move faster on scene on a device with higher processing capacity :- andengine

Tags: performance, sprite, andengine, processing

I am developing a game in which sprites move randomly on the screen. They move on paths defined by PathModifiers and their travel time is 7 seconds. Now the problem is that when i install my game in my phone which has a processing speed of 800MHz, it seems to work fine but when i install it on a device which has processing speed of 1GHz , it seems so much faster. Is this behaviour alright or i have something going wrong.

thanks

Comment: unlikely that small amount of increased processor speed is making all the difference, but hard to say without knowing the rest of the devices' specs.  more likely there's a substantial difference in the GPUs of the two.

Comment: How many sprites are you moving at the same time? If you reduce it to only one sprite, does the problem occur in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Check both scenarios with a chronometer. Is the "slower" one moving in 7 seconds? is it more or less? Do the same thing with the faster one. If both finish moving in 7 seconds, but it "feels faster", it means that is a fps "problem".